# instance member cannot be used in classname

Tags: swift

```
var collegeNames : String!

struct collegeName {
    static var clgName = collegeNames()
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> "instance variable 'collegenames' cannot be used on type 'ViewController' "

Comment: You can avoid this typo by following standard naming conventions. Class and struct names should begin with uppercase letters. Variable and method names begin with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to create a Singleton, but you have a typo in `collegeNames` and you need to replace `var` with `let` also, replace this line:

```
static var clgName = collegeNames()
```

With:

```
static let clgName = collegeName()
```

Comment: A singleton is usually a constant  (`let`)

Comment: The problem is not with `var` vs `let`. It is the typo in the class name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `collegeNames()` is incoherent. You cannot follow a variable name by parentheses; it makes no sense.

You'd be able to compile if you removed the parentheses; but the result, although it would compile, would still be a very silly thing to do, because you cannot give a `static var` a dynamic value; its value will always be `nil` because that's the value of `collegeNames`.

If the goal was to implement singleton, delete `collegeNames` altogether and initialize the static property to `collegeName()`. You would also use `let`, not `var`. The entire pattern would be greatly clarified if only you would obey the capitalization convention:

```
struct CollegeName {
    static var clgName = CollegeName()
}
```

That is the standard singleton pattern in Swift.